# Selecting rectangle / making it move

Tags: java, processing

Relevant code:

```
if (pic2 == true) {

  image(imgs[1],50,375);

} else {

  image(imgs[1],50,375);
  fill(255);
  rect(tboxPos,375,picWidth,picHeight);
  fill(0);
  textAlign(LEFT);
  text("text box 2...",420,395);

}
```

I'm using processing 2.2 and just added following library: http://benedikt-gross.de/libraries/Ani/

I want to use this for some kind of animation(my "rect" should slide from one side to the other. Ani seems to provide an easy solution to this, however I need to specify the "rect", so it doesn't select the image or text. Can this be done, by using Ani.to(this, ......), or do I have to specify it in another way?

I have to do this with several rectangles as well.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step one**: Store whatever you want to move in variables. For a rectangle, that's probably just the `x` and `y` values, and maybe the `width` and `height`:

```
float rectX = 25;
float rectY = 50;
float rectWidth = 10;
float rectHeight = 20;
```

**Step two**: Use those variables to draw your rect:

```
void draw(){
   background(0);
   rect(rectX, rectY, rectWidth, rectHeight);
}
```

**Step three:** Modify those variables to move your rect. You could use the Ani library to do that:

```
void setup(){
   Ani.init(this);
}
void mouseReleased(){
   Ani.to(this, 1.5, "rectX", mouseX);
   Ani.to(this, 1.5, "rectY", mouseY);
}
```

Note that there are many other ways to animate stuff, and you should probably get a better grasp of the basics before you try using a library like Ani. [Here](http://staticvoidgames.com/tutorials/basicConcepts/animation) is a tutorial that I wrote on basic animation in Processing.

**Step four**: Repeat those steps for whatever other objects you want to animate. An image will be similar to a rectangle.

Comment: I tried using your code, however I get an error at the Ani part, since it wants me to make the "1.5" a float

Comment: @Stenberg My code is just an example, but I took that code directly from [this Ani example](http://benedikt-gross.de/libraries/Ani/examples/Ani_Basics/Ani_Basics.pde). If you're in the Processing PDE, then 1.5 should already be a float. If not, you can cast it to a float or use a float literal: `1.5f`.